# Creating new instance of subclass of unknown type

Tags: kotlin

I have a class, Measurement

```
package robokt.measurement

abstract class Measurement : Number() {
    /**
     * The abbreviation for this unit of measurement
     */
    abstract val units: String
    /**
     * The abbreviation for this unit of measurement
     */
    abstract val value: Number
}
```

How can I implement the `unaryMinus()` operator fun, given that there are other classes implementing measurement, for example Inches:

```
package robokt.measurement.length

class Inches(override val value: Number) : Length() {
    override fun toCentimeters() = Centimeters(toDouble() * 2.54)

    override fun toFeet() = Feet(toDouble() / 12)

    override fun toInches() = this

    override fun toMeters() = Meters(toDouble() * 0.0254)

    override val units: String = "in"
}
```

Length is a simple abstract class that extends Measurement.

I would like to have `-Inches(5)` return `Inches(-5)`, but have that for any other class I create, like `-Degrees(30)` returning `Degrees(-30)`. Is there any way this is possible? I have tried generics, which ended up being a dead end.

Comment: Why don't you use https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement ?

Comment: I don't quite get your question: 1) Why Measurement extends Number() ? 2) You want to have unaryMinus() implemented on Measurement so you don't have to override it for all subclasses? 3) Length vs Inches classes is really bizarre IMO.

Comment: @mp911de I'm still learning, so I'm trying to do this on my own.

Comment: @RafalG., I thought a measurement is a number, so I extended Number. Yes, I don't want to override it in every subclass, and I don't understand your third question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make Measurement cloneable, you can clone it and cast (LOL) back to Measurement

```
abstract class Measurement : Cloneable {
  abstract val units: String
  abstract val value: Number

  fun unaryMinus() : Measurement {
      val measurement = this.clone() as Measurement
      return measurement
  }
}
```